# Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, mysql-workbench

Having spent a number of years working primarily with MS SQL Server (and hence SQL Server Management Studio for common tasks), I am now beginning to work with MySql. To date I have been using *MySQL Workbench* and am generally happy with it.

I would, however, like to be able to assign **custom keyboard shortcuts** for certain commands (e.g. commands from [this list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html)). For example, I'd prefer to stick to the MS-SQL approach of 'F5' to execute queries, rather than hitting 'Modifier+Return'. I haven't yet come across a simple way to do this. My questions are then:

- Is this possible somehow in MySQL Workbench (e.g. additional plugin)?
- If not, do any of the alternatives to MySQL Workbench offer this functionality?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32 bit
- MySQL server version 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
- MySQL Workbench Version 5.2.38, rev 8753

Cheers!

Comment: I wish I could upvote your question multiple times. I have returned here probably 10 times, because each time I upgrade my version of mysql-workbench, it wipes out my keybindings!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can modify the `main_menu.xml` file (for me on Ubuntu 12.04 this was in `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/`). After you modify it, you'll need to restart MySQL Workbench.

It'll look like this

```
    <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.query.exec"> 
      <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.query</link> 
      <value type="string" key="caption">Execute (All or Selection)</value> 
      <value type="string" key="name">query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="command">builtin:query.execute</value> 
      <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value> 
      <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+E</value>
    </value>
```

The second to last line (Modifier+E) was edited by me. Previously it said "Modifier+Shift+Return". Note that this is NOT an alias (you cannot have both).

Comment: Or if you want to make the keyboard match MS SQL Server, try this: <value type="string" key="shortcut">F5</value>

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench x.x\data\ for Windows users

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I located file in macOS (mac os x) as well. It sits here: `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/main_menu.xml`. Enjoy!

Comment: For windows x64 this file available under `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\data\main_menu.xml`

Comment: Note, when you upgrade workbench it overwrites your main_menu.xml, so save a backup of your customizations!