# Changing MySQL Workbench shortcut key mac osx?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I have mysql workbench installed on a mac. I am trying to use shortcuts for sql auto-complete. As per their documentation it is Modifier+Space
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Problem I have is that, Command+Space is configured to open spotlight for me and I want to keep it that way. Is there a way to modify the shortcut on workbench so i can make it control+space instead to do sql auto-complete?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking into main_menu.xml, the mac version actually uses CMD+ESC for the auto complete.  So you don't need to change anything.

FYI, file is inside the application package, at:
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/main_menu.xml

Comment: So *that's* what that funny-looking symbol next to the menu item for autocomplete means: Esc!

Answer (score 2):

**Mysql Workbench -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Productivity -> Automatically Start Code Completion**

BAM! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the below on SO, it is a very similar query however it answers for Ubuntu Linux. I think the same principal will apply however on your mac.

[Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in MySql Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043478/customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mysql-workbench)

Hope this helps.

Alec

Comment: Yeah i found that as well but its on Ubuntu and it works there but on osx, it does not have such files in that location.

Comment: The path on macos is `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/data/main_menu.xml` :)