# Modified keyboard shortcuts for MySQL Workbench not modified

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mysql-workbench

¿Title seems contradictory?  Let me explain.  I did find how to customize Workbench shortcuts, for example in the following link: [Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in MySql Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043478/customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mysql-workbench).

I think it was the update of the Workbench, or the whole going to Ubuntu 14.10, after which the modified shortcuts stopped working.  If I open the file *main_menu.xml*, I can see the shortcuts are indeed modified the way I want them to be, but the program won't recognize them and uses the default ones.

Would anyone know how to fix this?  Please help.

Comment: Seems to work from what I see. Can you file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com? Add your xml file in the report.

Comment: Thanks (I always avoid filing bugs =S ) http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75044&files=1

Comment: I can understand that people are reluctant, as they want a solution, not just tell a problem. But that's the only way for author to hear about the problems and have them properly scheduled to fix them.

Comment: Of course.  That's how to get involved.  =)